# How to I disable browsers from registering as Windows 10 media playback sources?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, browser, media-player

I have one native music streaming application which I keep open almost always and use media controls (play/pause, skip, etc). This app registers with Windows 10 as a media player - awesome.

Frequently I watch or listen to various video or audio sources in web browsers (firefox, chrome, etc) and every single page that has the potential to play some audio registers itself in this same Windows 10 media control interface.

This is immensely annoying because frequently (almost always) one of these little tabs takes precedence for media control and the play/pause button targets it instead of the native music application.

I would very much like to completely disable this functionality for browsers as it has been nothing but an irritation. I recognize that there are a couple solutions already such as closing the browsers but that is completely impractical for my day to day usage. I also often leave video tabs open to continue watching at a later time so closing them is not practical for me either.

Comment: Are you looking for media controls to just not work for browsers?

Comment: @harrymc That would probably suffice, yeah. My main gripe is that they populate each media source in the Windows media playback interface. Sounds like that would also remove them from that interface.

Comment: Which is your native music streaming application?

Comment: @harrymc The TIDAL Windows app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Chrome/Edge you can try to turn off this flag.

`chrome://flags/#hardware-media-key-handling` or `edge://flags/#hardware-media-key-handling`

If you don't want to global audio control to show up on the address bar turn off this one.

`chrome://flags/#global-media-controls` or `edge://flags/#global-media-controls`

Note: Google removed global-media-controls flag some versions earlier. So you can use command argument by starting browser as `chrome.exe --disable-features=GlobalMediaControls`

For Firefox open `about:config` page by entering it on address bar and search for `media.hardwaremediakeys.enabled`. Change to `false` by double-clicking.

[image: Disabling hardwaremediakeys on Firefox]

Comment: This looks like the solution - if you can embed the steps for Firefox, that would improve the answer quality.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution that will always send the Play/Pause media key to the TIDAL
player. The solution uses the free third-party product
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).
It also assumes that the TIDAL player has a window where the string "TIDAL" appears
in the title.

The following AutoHotkey script intercepts the media key and sends
<kbd>Space</kbd> to the TIDAL player:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2      ; a window's title can contain string anywhere to be a match
#IfWinExist TIDAL         ; only if exists a window whose title contains "TIDAL"
Media_Play_Pause::        ; map the play/pause media key
    ControlSend,, {Space}, TIDAL  ; send space to the window whose title contains "TIDAL"
```

The script may be extended to other keys supported by TIDAL.
As I don't have it installed, I'm limited to the documentation that
I found on internet.

After installing AutoHotKey, put the script in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit.
To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful documentation:

- [AutoHotKey List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Tidal keyboard shortcuts](https://defkey.com/tidal-desktop-shortcuts)

Comment: It would be best if you didn't have to install a global keylogger like AHK.